# Java input stream reads incompletely

Tags: java, ssl, https, webserver, inputstream

I've been working on a java web server and i have written most of it and now i'm working on TLS and HTTPS. The problem is that the input stream that i get from the SSLSocket reads the data incompletely. For example if the length of the data is 100,000 bytes it will read only 16,000 bytes, even the available() method of the input stream returns wrong number of bytes.
I tried to read all the bytes with readAllBytes() method or readFully() method (DataInputStream) but they won't work right because they will block and wait for more bytes to be received. (I used available() method while i was working on HTTP to exit the loop and it works fine but with the HTTPS it returns wrong number of bytes).
This is where i create the server socket :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",SSLConfigs.getJKS());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", SSLConfigs.getPass());
SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) 
SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) 
sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(Configs.getWSPort());
while (true) new HttpsHandler((SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept());
```

And this is HttpsHandler.java  (this is part i have problem with). I cache the request in a file called tempFile and the i do further processing on it:

```
FileOutputStream fw =  new FileOutputStream(tempFile,true);
fw.write(in.read());
while(in.available() > 0) {
fw.write(in.read());
}
```

and if it is a question, when i was writing the HTTP part, i had to start reading from the input stream buffer so that available() method wouldn't return 0 and i do the same thing here.
So basically the problem is that the code that i have written here does not read the data completely and when i did some debugging i found out that available() method return less number of bytes than the actual size of the data.
I have no idea how to fix this and i would appreciate your help very much!
(Sorry if its so long!)

Comment: It would probably be better to use existing HTTP server implementations instead of trying to implement your own because there is a lot to consider when implementing HTTP. Have you checked what these first 16,000 bytes contain and which HTTP headers they have?

Comment: Yes i've checked the headers but my problem is reading the entire stream, it worked fine wihtout TLS and i was able to read the stream completely.

Comment: Just trying to understand, is this a real code or a pseudo-code?

Comment: Using `available()` is definitely incorrect.  Please show us the code *before* you changed it to use `available()`.